# How to show filter options on your Android application?

Tags: filtering, android

For my Android Application, I want some options for my list-view, just like filter.

User can enter search text, select options by checking check-boxes.

Should I create another activity or I may have any other options?

It should be like preference for your activity.

Advises are appreciated.